# Closest matching string

Tags: python, logic, string-matching

I'm facing an issue which is related to string matching.
let's say for example i have 100 product ids starting from 1 to 100 and i have corresponding images with the product ids like, 1.jpg,1_1.jpg ,1_2.jpg ,1_3.jpg , 2_1.jpg,2_2.jpg,2_3.jpg ....100_1.jpg,100_2.jpg,100_3.jpg.

Now i want to add all the product ids and its corresponding images into a python dictionary

```
for i in productidlist:
    for j in imagelist:
        if i in j:
            productimagelist[i].append[j]
```

The issue with the above logic is, for the product id 1, it adds all the images which contains 1 in its name. And rest of the images also,like if the product id is 2, it will add all the images which has 2 in its name. So , on.

This problem is not only to limited to the above product ids. If the product id is a substring of another product id, this issue will arise. Please help me with this problem. I need a logic to tackle this problem. rite now i'm thinking of closest string match. But im not sure it works. Please help me with this

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in productidlist:
    for j in imagelist:
        if j.startswith(str(i) + '_'):
            productimagelist[i].append[j]
```